# PeakDetect Function Behavior and Parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization, peak-detection

I am currently using PeakDetect for a project, but I'm not sure how the sharpness parameter works. I can qualitatively tell what it's doing, but is there a more analytical/mathematical way to define sharpness?

Comment: You can read a detailed answer about how `FindPeaks` works in my answer to the question [Find a local maximum in list without using built-in function FindPeaks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186638/731). `PeakDetect` seems to be a version of `FindPeaks` that returns a binary list instead of a list of positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see from my reimplementation of `FindPeaks` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186638/731) that the sharpness parameter is a threshold that discards all peaks for which the negative of the second derivative is smaller than that threshold.

I implemented it like this:

```
findPeaks1[data_, sigma_, s_] := Module[{sharpness},
  sharpness = ListConvolve[{1, -2, 1}, data];
  Unitize[findPeaks1[data, sigma] + 1 - Unitize[sharpness, s]]
  ]
```

You can see here the exact definition, how the second derivative is computed and how the threshold is applied.